# .htaccess file, RewriteRule is working partially

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to write some rewrite rules in .htaccess file in order to redirect the old pages of the website to the new php pages. Two of the rules are not working, any idea?

The rules are similar, they are trying to redirect for example from
`www.prova.com/YC/13123.html` to  `www.prova.com/YC/YC.php?capitolo=13123`

the  rules are working except for "YC" and "thegamer" (there is a comment in the code added to explain which one).

```
RewriteRule ^.*YC/(.*)\.(html)$ YC/YC.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301] <-- not working
RewriteRule ^.*RS/(.*)\.(html)$ RS/RS.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*BB/(.*)\.(html)$ BB/BB.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*thegamer/(.*)\.(html)$ thegamer/Gamer.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301] <-- not working
RewriteRule ^.*CB/(.*)\.(html)$ CB/CB.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*Hellper/(.*)\.(html)$ Hellper/Hellper.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*Dice/(.*)\.(html)$ Dice/Dice.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*Lars/(.*)\.(html)$ Lars/Lars.php?capitolo=$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, for mistake i uploaded another .htaccess in the 2 folder that were not working :)